# StimulusJS EventListener for custom events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragula, stimulusjs

I'm using StimulusJS in my Rails 6 application and I need to create a custom event listener on a `data-action` attribute to build a drag and drop functionality using `dragula.js`.

Inside the controller it's easy to capture the event according to the docs:

```
let containers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".drag-container"))
let drag = dragula(containers)
            
drag.on("drop", (el, target) => {
 console.log(el)
 console.log(target)
})
```

But I want to capture the event on the element directly, is this somehow possible? Listening for the normal drop event doesn't work :/.

```
 <div class="p-3 drag-container" data-action="drop->draggable#dropping" data-draggable-bed-value="<%= bed.id %>"></div>
```

Comment: How are you sending the event? with something like this `const event = new CustomEvent("drop"); window.dispatchEvent(event);` you can listen the event like so `data-action="drop@window->drop#dropping"`

Comment: Can you post more of your controller and view? I'm assuming you have some targets defined. For instance, I might have each drag container div be a `data-target="draggable.dragcontainer"`. You could then call `this.dragcontainerTargets` in your controller to get all of them at once.